# Mass Find and Replace PHP Files

Tags: php, replace, terminal, find

I am currently in the process of moving all my standard class functions to static functions.
eg : `$input->post()` to `Input::post();`

I have lots of instances and files which are affected by this change and was wondering if anyone knew a way I could find and replace `$input->` with `Input::` in a quick method rather than the time consuming going into each file and manually replacing.

Preferably a terminal command, the files are on a Debian server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: any good IDE has this functionality...

Comment: What IDE would you suggest, Most of my work is done in notepadd++ or VIM

Comment: Both NotePad++ and VIM has this functionality.

Comment: Notepad++ allows you to do this

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Vim, from the [Vim documentation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace):

```
:%s/foo/bar/g
```

Find each occurrence of 'foo' (in all lines), and replace it with 'bar'.

Comment: assign it to a macro, load all files and run the macro